# FFMPEG zoompan for continuous zoom in/zoom out from start duration

Tags: ffmpeg

I am creating continues zoomin/zoomout effect for input image using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i combine.mp4 -i image1.jpg -filter_complex "[0]split=2[color][alpha]; 
[color]crop=iw/2:ih:0:0[color]; [alpha]crop=iw/2:ih:iw/2:ih[alpha]; [colo][alpha]alphamerge[v1];
[1]scale=540*2:960*2, setsar=1, zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.02,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=25*0.25:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=540x960[v2]; 
[v2]zoompan=z='if(gte(zoom,1.1),1.0,min(zoom+0.0015,1.1))':d=25*0.25:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=540x960[v2];
[v2]curves=vintage, format=yuv444p[v2];
[v2][v1] overlay=1" output_video.mp4 -y
```

This command will continues `zoomin` and `zoomout` input `image1.jpg` for 1 second and stop after 1 second its OK. But problem is I want perform `zoomin` `zoomout` effect after 5 second of video. Video duration is 20s. So, how can I perform `zoompan` after some duration.